# Iphone only app cuts of the bottom of the screen when viewed in Ipad mode (2x)

Tags: iphone, resolution, iphone-3gs

my app is very basic and looks great on the iphone but in compatability mode 2x on the ipad it does not show the same screen as on the iphone. it was built as an iphone only app and has no major graphs. this is what Apple told me. 2.10: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same behavior on a physical iPad 2 for an existing working iPhone-only app.

In fact, after adding for each Retina images (suffixed by @2x) a corresponding non-Retina version in the project, my app launched successfully on the iPad, without any modifications...

I'm not sure it will work for you, but might worth to try ?

Comment: Hi, did this work for you? I have the same problem, but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @LucasA In fact, when I did only that for ALL low-def images, the app work seamlessly on iPad without any other modifications... are you sure, you have it all assets, including splash screen and all app icons ?

Comment: I just checked all assets.. But I forgot the app icons.. could this be it? I will try it now and get back to you. If this works, this should REALLY be marked as correct answer, since this issue is VERY time consuming. Thanks for the help @cdescours

Comment: Yea, just tested it and still no luck @cdescours .. The bottom part is still cropped. :( This turns out to be a huge problem for me. I have all the required assets as far as I know.

Comment: What about your Info.plist? did you specify your assets/icons names there?

Comment: Also, sorry for so many questions, but did you have to add other images non-Retina version too? For example, a button img would need to have the default and the 2x images?

Comment: @LucasA In fact I had to add a non-Retina and Retina for ALL images (including buttons, splashcreen, backgrounds... or whatever !) ! I did not make any changes to the .plist. Have you checked when debugging the frame of your view at runtime ? Is it a correct, or is it cropped by a wrong line of code ?

Comment: Hmm I will definitely try that, thanks! One more question, did you by any chance add iPad images? Like Default-Portrait.png (or its 2x), or only iPhone imgs?

Comment: In fact I've just added iPhone only images... If you provide iPad images, iOS will look for a storyboard designed for iPad or something like that, so I suppose this will not work for you.

Comment: Solved it! It was actually a problem with pixels! In my code, at some points I was using px instead of dip, and it somehow made everything messy. Thanks!